# Solution to bivariate normally distributed problem

Tags: calculus, integration, bivariate-distributions

Is anyone able to solve the following integral with a normal bivariate PDF, or at least to clarify if there exist a closed form solution?

Thanks in advance.

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\beta x}\max\{K-Ae^{\alpha y},0\}e^\frac{-(x^2+y^2-2xy\rho)}{2}d{x}d{y}
\end{equation}

Comment: The Gaussian $x$ integral may be done immediately. The $y$ integral that remains will give an error function, because the $\text{max}\{...\}$ term restricts the integration range of $y$